# jQuery BBQ, Address or any other hashchange plugin - Recommendation

Tags: ajax, jquery, hashchange

I am looking for a plugin or function that gives you SEO friendly way of dynamically loading pages, bookmarking via Ajax. I know this has been asked a lot.

The things that irriate me: I used to go with jquery.address plugin for it, but to be honest this plugin always seems quite complex to handle. I also looked at other plugins, e.g. jQuery BBQ. I know it's recommended quite a lot. But: the plugin hasn't been updated for 2 years now ([link](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq)). Now I am wondering if there is anything that I am missing or even if it's included in jQuery 1.9. Nevertheless I checked jQuery documentation and I couldn't seem to find anything.

Since I am using ajax quite a lot lately and I would love to know what other people use and I am glad for any recommendations.

Many thanks and best,

Mike

Comment: ditto. I'm using bbq and running into an edge case problem. there's not much of a support community out there for it :/